# Can't get Invoke() to work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
//Tring to add a delay before game restarts

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    bool GameEnded = false;

    public float RestartDelay = 4f;

    public void CompleteLevel ()
    {
        Debug.Log("1!");
    }

    public void GameOver ()
    {
        if (GameEnded == false) 
        {
            GameEnded = true;
            Debug.Log("Game Over");
            Invoke("Restart", RestartDelay);
            Restart();

        }
    }

    void Restart ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Could it be that this line of code is the issue? ```SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);``` What happens when you set a breakpoint in your Restart() method? Does it hit it? Also, what calls the GameOver() method?

Comment: Have you checked to see whether `Restart` is being called (_twice_, becaise you're both invoking it and calling it directly)? Adding a `Debug.Log` to the method would clarify where the problem really is. You also don't explain in your question where `GameOver` is called from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Invoke` to call `Restart()` after a certain delay but then you directly call `Restart()` which will load the next scene.

What `Invoke` does is allow you to schedule method calls to occur after a certain time. You seem to be using it as a function that will make the process wait a certain amount of time which is wrong.

Simply remove the `Restart()` call after `Invoke("Restart", RestartDelay);`